# How to deploy Report Viewer Runtime for projects developed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, redistributable, report-viewer2012

I have converted the VS 2013 WinForm project to VS 2015. Once I installed it on client, report viewer is asking for Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 12.0.0.0.

With VS 2013 projects Report Viewer 2012 Runtime worked fine.

I haven't been able to locate anywhere newer version of Report Viewer Runtime.

Does anyone know where can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of .net framework do your application use?

Comment: How do yo install your application on client? `XCopy`? `ClickOnce`?

Comment: I Looked into my project references these are references that it uses:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` and 

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` You can set `Copy Local` to true for these references.

Comment: the latest version is 2015 of the report viewer which is downloadable at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Comment: @jacob_Zac => did you get this to work?